# Update or insert with outer join in postgres

Tags: postgresql, join

Is it possible to add a new column to an existing table from another table using `insert` or `update` in conjunction with `full outer join` .

In my main table i am missing some records in one column in the other table i have all those records i want to take the full record set into the maintable table. Something like this;

```
UPDATE maintable 
SET all_records= othertable.records
FROM 
FULL JOIN othertable on maintable.col = othertable.records;
```

Where maintable.col has same id a othertable.records.

I know i could simply join the tables but i have a lot of comments in the maintable i don't want to have to copy paste back in if possible. As i understand using `where` is equivalent of a `left join` so won't show me what i'm missing

EDIT: 
What i want is effectively a new maintable.col with all the records i can then pare down based on presence of records in other cols from other tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE maintable 
SET all_records = o.records
FROM othertable o
WHERE maintable.col = o.records;
```

This is the general syntax to use in postgres when updating via a join.

HTH

EDIT

BTW you will need to change this - I used your example, but you are updating the maintable with the column used for the join!  Your set needs to be something like SET missingcol = o.extracol

AMENDED GENERALISED ANSWER (following off-line chat)

To take a simplified example, suppose that you have two tables maintable and subtable, each with the same columns, but where the subtable has extra records.  For both tables id is the primary key.  To fill maintable with the missing records, for pre 9.5 versions of Postgres you must use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO maintable (SELECT * FROM subtable s WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM maintable m WHERE m.id = s.id));
```

Since 9.5 there is a (preferred) alternative:

```
INSERT INTO maintable (SELECT * FROM subtable) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

This is preferred because (apart from being simpler) it avoids the situation that has been known to arise in the former, where a race condition is created between the INSERT and the sub-SELECT.

Obviously when the columns are different, you need to specify in the INSERT statement which columns are inserted from which.  Something like:

```
INSERT INTO maintable (id, ColA, ColB) 
(SELECT id, ColE, ColG FROM subtable ....)
```

Similarly the common field might not be id in both tables. However, the simplified example should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: But that would only give me all the records i already have in the maintable  whereas i want to use the all_records column to understand what i'm missing. I've edited the question to make that clearer

Comment: Are you talking about missing rows or missing columns?  Your question is really not clear.

Comment: If you are talking about missing rows, then you do not want an UPDATE statement, since by definition that only acts on rows that exist.  Instead you need an INSERT (probably with WHERE NOT EXISTS ..)

Comment: Thank you, yes rows. Sounds like INSERT and WHERE NOT EXISTS is what i'm looking for

Comment: Which version of Postgres are you using.  I ask because since 9.5 there is the possibility to do INSERT  .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

Comment: 9.6 what i've tried seems to be working using not exists , now have col all_records and the original which give correct number rows. so can update from all_records into maintable.col where maintable.col is null, i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149792/discussion-between-mapping-dom-and-jonathan-willcock).